ScreenBroadcast UI Extension Error: connection to plugin interrupted while in use
I am trying to setup BroadcastUIExtension but I am keep getting this error.
[com.apple.ReplayKit.RPBroadcastActivityViewControllerExtension(1.0)] Connection to plugin interrupted while in use.

Currently I have target ScreenBroadcastExtension & ScreenBroadcastUIExtension.
If I directly use ScreenBroadcastExtension the default system alert is triggered to record screen and its working.
